# "Agent History Clean Up: Distribution" and "Distribution Clean Up: Distribution" Missing when Creating Merge Replication Instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, database-replication, merge-replication

I've noticed recently that my distribution db is massive, and while searching for solutions, I keep coming across articles mentioning that these 2 jobs should be running:

"Agent History Clean Up: Distribution" and
"Distribution Clean Up: Distribution"

Other users have reported that these seem to be disabled by default, but, I do not see them at all(under SQL Server Agent > Jobs). To ensure that it wasn't something to do with my specific instance of replication, I created a dummy instance and the jobs were still not created.

How do I ensure that these are properly created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to completely disable distribution on the server, and re-configure it, from scratch (I used the GUI).